# How to check if a string does not equal another string in an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, equals, string-comparison

In this first part of code it checks if the user entered a username and password that matches, and if it does, then we log in the client. This part of code is fine. It works when it is supposed to.

First code:

```
//If the user entered a username & pass that matches a stored user & pass
if (incomingClients[i].username == existingClients[e].username) {
    if (incomingClients[i].password == existingClients[e].password) {
        //LogInClient();
    }
}
```

In this second part, it is supposed to check if the user entered a username that does NOT exist, and if it doesn't exist, then we tell the user that he/she has entered a username that does not exist.

Second code:

```
//If the user entered a username that DOES NOT match a stored user
if (incomingClients[i].username != existingClients[e].username) {
    //NotifyClientUserDoesntExist();
}
```

The problem I am having here is that the second code is always true. Why is this?

If I enter a username that exists the first code executes, but so does the second code. I only want the second code to execute if the incoming.username is not equal to existing.username.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please show an [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You haven't even told us the type of `username`, which is fairly important.

Answer (score 0):

Because probably your check is inside a for loop lile

```
for (int e = 0; e < existingClients.size(); ++e) {
  if (incomingClients[i].username == existingClients[e].username)
    if (...) {

    }

  if (incomingClients[i].username != existingClients[e].username) {
    ..
  }
}
```

But logic is incorrect because you consider a user that doesn't exist as soon as you find one existing client with a different user name. The code should be something like:

```
const auto& user = find_if(begin(existingClients), end(existingClients), [](const User& user) { return user.username == existingClients[i].username; }

bool isExistingLogin = user != existingClients.end();
bool isCorrectLogin = isExistingLogin && user->password == incomingUsers[i].password;
```

So that a login exists if any of `existingClients` has correct user name, and it's correct if it exists and password matches.

Answer (score 0):

Why not do this?

```
if (incomingClients[i].username == existingClients[e].username) {
    if (incomingClients[i].password == existingClients[e].password) {
        //LogInClient();
    }
}
else {
    //NotifyClientUserDoesntExist();
}
```